# Can't automate mobile application (write in RAD studio)

Tags: android, delphi, automated-tests, c++builder

I am trying to automate a mobile application, but UI Automator Viewer can't recognize any control.
RAD studio makes apk file, I work with it.
The type of app is native.
I always get this result:

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, UI Automator Viewer only works with Java apps that use native Android controls. Android apps written in Delphi/C++Builder/RADStudio are not Java-based and do not use native Android controls. There is a small Java stub to get the Activity running, but that is all, everything else is native ARM code, and Embarcadero's FireMonkey frameworks uses custom-made controls that are manually drawn in the style of Android, and do not implement Android's accessibility APIs.  There are some third-party packages that do use native Android controls, such as [DPF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/), but I do not know if UI Automator Viewer can see them.